# How to use jquery or ajax to update razor partial view in c#/asp.net for a MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, c#-4.0, razor

In a MVC partial view file, I build one Html.TextBox and two submit buttons. These two buttons will increase/decrease the Html.TextBox value once clicked. The Html.TextBox displayed value will change accordingly.However, once I need to update the #refTable div based on the new value after click. The page or section never updated. Codes are below, where some comments are added for explanation purpose. Thanks for your help.

//*************** cshtml file  ******************//

```
<body>
</body>

<input type="submit" value="PrevY" name="chgYr2" id="pY" />
@{
    var tempItem3 = Model.First(); // just give the first entry from a database, works.
    if (ViewData["curSel"] == null)
    {
    @Html.TextBox("yearSelect3", Convert.ToDateTime(tempItem3.Holiday_date).Year.ToString());  
    ViewBag.selYear = Convert.ToDateTime(tempItem3.Holiday_date).Year; // just initial value, works
    ViewData["curSel"] = Convert.ToDateTime(tempItem3.Holiday_date).Year;
    }
    else
    {
    @Html.TextBox("yearSelect3", ViewData["curSel"].ToString());
    } 
}
<input type="submit" value="NextY" name="chgYr2" id="nY" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click", "#nY", function () {
            var val = $('#yearSelect3').val();
            $('#yearSelect3').val((val * 1) + 1);
            var dataToSend = {
                id: ((val * 1) + 1)
            }
            // add some jquery or ajax codes to update the #refTable div
            // also ViewBag.selYear need to be updated as ((val * 1) + 1)
            // like:   ViewBag.selYear = ((val * 1) + 1);
            // any similar temp variable is fine
        });

        });
        $(document).on("click", "#pY", function () {
            var val = $('#yearSelect3').val();
            $('#yearSelect3').val((val * 1) - 1);
            var dataToSend = {
                id: ((val * 1) - 1)
            }

        });
    });
</script>



<span style="float: right"><a href="/">Set Holiday Calender for 2013</a></span>
<span id="btnAddHoliday">@Html.ActionLink("Add Holiday", "Create", null, new { id = "addHilBtn" })</span>

<div id="refTable">
    <table class="tblHoliday" style="width: 100%;">
            <th>
                Holiday
            </th>
            <th>
                Dates
            </th>
            <th>Modify</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            if (    Convert.ToDateTime(item.Holiday_date).Year == ViewBag.selYear)
            // if the ViewBag.selYear is hard code, this selection "works"
            {
            <tr>                
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Name)
                </td>               
                <td>
                    @item.Holiday_date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {  })
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        }

    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the AJAX code that you have tried?

Comment: I took the ajax out, since these ajax are used for calling MVC actions. I tried to refresh the webpage via execute MVC actions, in vain.

Answer (score 82):

You'll need AJAX if you want to update a part of your page without reloading the entire page.

**main cshtml view**

```
<div id="refTable">
     <!-- partial view content will be inserted here -->
</div>

@Html.TextBox("yearSelect3", Convert.ToDateTime(tempItem3.Holiday_date).Year.ToString());
<button id="pY">PrevY</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#pY").on("click", function() {
            var val = $('#yearSelect3').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Holiday/Calendar",
                type: "GET",
                data: { year: ((val * 1) + 1) }
            })
            .done(function(partialViewResult) {
                $("#refTable").html(partialViewResult);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

You'll need to add the fields I have omitted. I've used a `<button>` instead of submit buttons because you don't have a form (I don't see one in your markup) and you just need them to trigger javascript on the client side.

The **HolidayPartialView** gets rendered into html and the jquery `done` callback inserts that html fragment into the **refTable** div.

**HolidayController Update action**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Calendar(int year)
{
    var dates = new List<DateTime>() { /* values based on year */ };
    HolidayViewModel model = new HolidayViewModel {
        Dates = dates
    };
    return PartialView("HolidayPartialView", model);
}
```

This controller action takes the year parameter and returns a list of dates using a strongly-typed view model instead of the ViewBag.

**view model**

```
public class HolidayViewModel
{
    IEnumerable<DateTime> Dates { get; set; }
}
```

**HolidayPartialView.csthml**

```
@model Your.Namespace.HolidayViewModel;

<table class="tblHoliday">
    @foreach(var date in Model.Dates)
    {
        <tr><td>@date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td></tr>
    }
</table>
```

This is the stuff that gets inserted into your div.

Comment: ok, I like you're solution but why use done? why don't just use success callback of ajax?

Comment: `Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.` [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Hello Jorge, Thank you very much for your help. Appreciate!! As to the using of "callback of ajax". Sorry, I am still new to ajax and MVC, and need some time to digest them.

Comment: .done(function(partialViewResult) {
                $("#refTable").html(partialViewResult);
            });
Explain above code block in detail.

Answer (score 2):

The main concept of partial view is returning the HTML code rather than going to the partial view it self.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Calendar(int year)
{
    var dates = new List<DateTime>() { /* values based on year */ };
    HolidayViewModel model = new HolidayViewModel {
        Dates = dates
    };
    return PartialView("HolidayPartialView", model);
}
```

this action return the HTML code of the partial view ("HolidayPartialView").

To refresh partial view replace the existing item with the new filtered item using the jQuery below.

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/Holiday/Calendar",
                type: "GET",
                data: { year: ((val * 1) + 1) }
            })
            .done(function(partialViewResult) {
                $("#refTable").html(partialViewResult);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Url.Action for the path instead like so:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Holiday", "Calendar", new { area = "", year= (val * 1) + 1 })",                
        type: "GET",           
        success: function (partialViewResult) {            
            $("#refTable").html(partialViewResult);
        }
    });
```