# How to filter data on screen with ajax using dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Iv searched similar questions, but still have a little trouble with this.

I am in ASP.NET MVC, and in the Index action of my HomeController, I am populating my Model with data from my database.

Model

```
    public class DataTableModel
{
    //regular list to hold data from database
    public List<DataRow> list { get; set; }

    //pagedList to setup pagination
    public PagedList<DataRow> plist { get; set; }

    //List of column headers to display at the top of the data table
    public List<string> columnHeaders { get; set; }

    //Values to display in flat report filter dropdown
    public List<string> comboBoxFilerValues { get; set; }

}
```

My controller sends this model to my View.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string filter, int? page)
    {
        DataTableModel lifeUsageReport = new DataTableModel();
        lifeUsageReport.columnHeaders = new List<string>();
        lifeUsageReport.list = data.GetLifeUsageReport(filter).Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList();
        lifeUsageReport.plist = new PagedList<DataRow>(lifeUsageReport.list, page ?? 1, 10);
        lifeUsageReport.comboBoxFilerValues = new List<string>();
        foreach(DataColumn column in data.GetLifeUsageReport(filter).Tables[0].Columns)
        {
            lifeUsageReport.columnHeaders.Add(column.Caption);
        }
        foreach(DataRow row in data.GetLifeUsageReport(filter).Tables[1].Rows)
        {
            lifeUsageReport.comboBoxFilerValues.Add(row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
        }
        return View(lifeUsageReport);
    }
```

In my View, I am displaying this data to the screen.

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("Filter", new SelectList(Model.comboBoxFilerValues), new { @id = "filterDropdown" })

<div id="reportTable">
<table id="lifeUsage">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var column in Model.columnHeaders)
            {
                <td>
                    @column
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.plist)
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
            {
                <td>@cell</td>
            }
        </tr>

    }
</table>
</div>
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.plist, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page}))
```

The dropdown list in my view currently has 2 values. I want the data to filter based on the value selected. The data filters properly when I add a parameter to the URL by hand. I want to make the dropdownlist do this.

Iv added a script section at the bottom of my view, and I am trying to use Ajax to accomplish this, but I am still new in the subject, so I am not exactly sure what I am doing.

```
@section scripts
{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#filterDropdown').change(function () {

            var filter = $('#filterDropdown').val();//value from dropdown list

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
                data : {
                    "filter" : filter  //I think this is supposed to be the value of the dropdown list?
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("it worked");
                }

            });
        });
```

});

Can anyone show me how to properly set up this Ajax function to take the value from the dropdown list, send it to the Index action, and bring back the proper data for me to re-display on the screen?

Comment: The essential parts are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392212/how-to-use-jquery-or-ajax-to-update-razor-partial-view-in-c-asp-net-for-a-mvc-p/19410973#19410973). The difference is you get the value from a dropdown instead of a textbox but you seem to have that covered.

Comment: @Jasen This is perfect, I was able to accomplish what I was trying to do with this reference. If you put it into an answer, ill select it.