# How to make a AJAX GET call in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am learning web development. And I just want to make a simple AJAX GET call in ASP.Net MVC Application and I want visualize how it works. But I am not able to do so. I am a beginner and I could have done any silly mistakes. But as of now there are no errors in my code.

Below is what I have:

So, I have a `Index.cshtml` file which is already loaded. Now in that page I want to make an `Ajax GET call` to one of the `function` that I have written in the `HomeController` and action name is `Test`. I just want to hit the breakpoint in that `Test Action` of Homecontroller and return something back to the `Success` of AJAX Call.
In HomeController I have below Action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return View("hello");
}
```

jQuery

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Test',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (html) {
            alert(html);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            $(that).remove();
            DisplayError(error.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

Confusion: Do I need to create a `cshtml` for `Test`. But I actually do not want that. I just want the `Test` Action to return me one data. And I will display that data in my Already opened `Index.csthml` file.

Error: No error but I am not able to hit the breakpoint in `Test Action` of controller. Kindly note that `Success` of AJAX is hitting but I do not see any data. But I am sure it did not hit the test Action breakpoint.

Comment: when are you calling your ajax code ? Any event triggers that code ? other wise your code is fine.

Comment: GET requests may be cached by the browser. If you had called it once it may not reach your controller again. Watch the browser's network monitor to verify the request is made.

Comment: There was a big answer down here for my question but now that answer is gone. :(

Comment: yes I need that ajax call to get triggered on a function call. And that function call is working fine. This ajax request is getting hit.

Comment: What kind of response do you want returned? A HTML fragment or JSON?

Comment: just anything. I just want to get something back.

Comment: Here's an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392212/how-to-use-jquery-or-ajax-to-update-razor-partial-view-in-c-asp-net-for-a-mvc-p/19410973#19410973) for a HTML fragment returned with a PartialView.

Comment: As of now. I always get the success call back but I get the content of success is another function which in in the controller Home and action named "INDEX". Why the Index action is getting hit??

Comment: I don't want a partial view. I want to return just a content. please guide me.

Comment: Then there's a good [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17734878/2030565).

Answer (score 4):

Change your action method like this

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Test()
{
    return Json("myContent",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And in your success method in 'html' variable you will get back "myContent".

Answer (score 3):

Example :

```
 function RemoveItem(ItemId) {

                if (ItemId && ItemId > 0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        cache: false,
                        url: '@Url.Action("RemoveItem", "Items")',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { id: ItemId },
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.success == true) {
                                $("#CartItemGridDiv").load('@Url.Content("~/User/Items/CartItemGrid")');
                                alert('Item Removed successfully.');
                            }
                            else {
                                alert('Item not removed.');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert('Item not removed.');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        public ActionResult RemoveItem(int id)
        {
            if (id > 0)
            {
                bool addToChart = false;

                addToChart = Utilities.UtilityClass.RemoveItem(id);

                if (addToChart)
                {
                    return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
            public ActionResult CartItemGrid()
        {
            List<CartItems> oItemList = (List<CartItems>)Session[MvcMAB.StringConst.CartItemSession];
            return View(oItemList);
        }
```

Comment: but id is going as url paramter visible in url , if i dont want that then?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to return a view, you might need to return `Json()` instead of `View()`
You need to Allow Get in the action. Like that:

```
    public ActionResult SomeGetAction(int? id)
    {
       //Some DB query here
       var myJsonList = myListQuery;
       return Json(myJsonList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Or in case of just Simple string response:

```
 public ActionResult SomeGetAction()
    {

       return Json("My String", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I would recommend renaming `html` into `response`.
Also change `that` to `this` in Error Response section.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/Home/Test',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        $(this).remove();
        DisplayError(error.statusText);
    }
});
```

Enjoy.

Comment: I do  not understand your answer. I just want to return one string. may be "hello world".

Comment: What is this `int? id and myListQuery and all`.

Comment: @Unbreakable then return Json("Hello WOrld", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: @Unbreakable check my answer, I Edited it.

Comment: What about the ajax call. Do I need to change something in ajax call too. Can you see my ajax code..

Comment: @Unbreakable I edited my answer, You don't really need to change anything in you ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

C#:

```
public JsonResult Test()
    {
        return Json("hello");
    }
```

Jquery:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Test',
        type: 'Post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (html) {
            alert(html);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
                       }
    });
```