# Partial View Render

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am new to the world of MVC programming with C #, I already read the topic, made some examples and of course with the guide of StackOverflow I think I'm doing well.

However I find myself with an exercise that I want to perform and from which I have seen several answers but none has worked for me, and I come to you asking for the support.

**Index**

```
  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Bienvenido";
}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="menu">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Datos Generales</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Datos Curriculares</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Experiencia Laboral</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Datos Laborales</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dependientes">Cónyuge y Dependientes</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Inmuebles</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Vehículos</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Muebles</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Inversiones</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Adeudos</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Posible Conflicto de Intereses</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Observaciones</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row" id="opciones">

            </div>
            <div class="row" id="crear">

            </div>
            <div class="row" id="registros">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#dependientes').click(function () {
            $.get('@Url.Action("Create","Dependientes")', function (data) {
                $('#crear').replaceWith(data);
            });
        });
    });
     $(function () {
        $('#dependientes').click(function () {
            $.get('@Url.Action("Mostrar","Dependientes")', function (data) {
                $('#registros').replaceWith(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Partial View _Mostrar**

```
@model List<projectD.Models.dependiente>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_Mostrar";
}
<br />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="card" style="width: 20rem; display:inline-block; margin-top:10px">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="~/Content/images/familia.png" alt="Card image cap" width="50" height="50">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Dependiente</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        @item.nombre
                        <br />
                        @item.apellidoPaterno
                        <br />
                        @item.apellidoMaterno
                        <br />
                        @item.CURP
                    </p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Detalle", "Details", new { id = item.idDependiente }, new {@class= "btn btn-primary"})
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a project with a main view, which has a menu to the left when selecting each option to the right render two partial views each with its controller the first to add records and the second to display them.
[main screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ5Iz.png)

What I want to do is that when I click on add record, only the partial views are updated and the URL is not reloaded since I would lose the menu option in which I am.

I hope you can support me

Comment: You'll need to use AJAX if you want a partial update _without_ page navigation (page reload).

Comment: Here is an [AJAX example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392212/how-to-use-jquery-or-ajax-to-update-razor-partial-view-in-c-asp-net-for-a-mvc-p).

Comment: What is the exact nature of your issue. You've already got some AJAX going on, so what's not working? What problems are you running into?

Comment: My issue is to know if I am fine-tuning the Ajax function since doing the examples does not work the way I want it. Have a view with three div on the left with a menu and the right with a create view and another to display. Adding a record to the create refreshes the entire page.

Does the Ajax code go inside the main view or the create page?

Thank yo