# How to load another view as PartialView when the current View loads?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am relatively new to this. I am working on this `ASP.NET Core MVC` project where I want to load a `PartialView`, `HistoryTable.cshtml` in a `<div>` in the current `Main View` when the `Main View`, `Locate.cshtml` loads. In other words, I want the `PartialView` to be there whenever the `MainView` loads/reloads.

I am implementing it in the following way:

**Locate.cshtml**

```
@model Project.Models.CustomModels.LocationsHistoryViewModel
<div class="container">
...
    <div id="divLocationsHistoryTable"></div>
...
</div>

@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".disabledropdowncntrl").prop('disabled', false).trigger("chosen:updated");
        $("#divLocationsHistoryTable").load("/Project/HistoryTable");
    });
```

**HistoryTable.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.CustomModels.LocationsHistoryViewModel>
<div class="card">
...
@if(Model.Count() != 0)
{
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column-id="UserId" data-type="string" data-identifier="true" hidden>User ID</th>
            <th data-column-id="Name">Name</th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>

}
else
{
    ...
}
<tbody>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.User.FirstName @item.User.LastName
            </td>
            ...
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</div>
```

**Controller: Locate ActionMethod**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Locate(int Id, InventoryLocationsHistoryViewModel locationsHistoryVM)
{
    ...
    var HistoryObject = _context.History
        .Include(...
        .Where(...
        .Select(...
    {
        ...
    }).ToList();

    return PartialView("/Project/HistoryTable", HistoryObject);
}
```

What to do?

**EDIT**

The issue that I am facing is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392212/how-to-use-jquery-or-ajax-to-update-razor-partial-view-in-c-asp-net-for-a-mvc-p), however, the difference is that I HAVE to use `Submit` button here as I am submitting `form` here. The `Submit` button has to do two things when clicked:

1. Save the `form` details into the database.
2. Update the `HistoryTable` that has to be displayed below the `Submit` button always. This `HistoryTable` has to be shown at all times (even before clicking `Submit`). Thus, I cannot use `Button`.

Comment: `.load("/Project/HistoryTable")` is `.load(url_to_action)` not the view template name. But in this case you're looking for the `Locate()` action. Futhermore, your action requires parameters which your AJAX request is not sending.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jquery or ajax to update razor partial view in c#/asp.net for a MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392212/how-to-use-jquery-or-ajax-to-update-razor-partial-view-in-c-asp-net-for-a-mvc-p)

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of issues here, making it a little difficult to figure out what it is you're actually trying to achieve.

First and foremost, your `Locate` action should return your `Locate.cshtml` view, on both GET and POST. The fact that that view includes your `HistoryTable.cshtml` partial view is an implementation detail.  If you only return the partial on POST, you'll only have the partial HTML in the browser, not the full `Locate` view.

Then, it appears that you're attempting to use jQuery's `load` method to load your actual partial, not an action that returns that partial. You can't get the view directly; you need to submit an AJAX request (what `load` is doing) to a *route* tied to an action that returns that partial.

Next, it looks like your partial needs a payload, i.e. some object needs to be "posted" for it to work with. If that's the case, you need to pass a JavaScript object representation of what you need to post to the `load` method as its second parameter. As it is, it's simply going to issue a GET request directly, passing no data.

However, since you're only doing this on page load, it calls into question why you're using AJAX at all. AJAX only makes sense if you need to change something *later*, after page load. If you're doing an AJAX request on load, it should simply be built into the page from the start, negating the need for a separate request.

Lastly, while you can pass a model to a partial view when you include it in a page, more likely than not what you're actually looking for here is a [view component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components), i.e. something capable of actually doing logic like querying from a database, separate from the main request in play.