# (Newbie to APS.NET)MVC possibility for partilal page refresh without using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have experience on Web development on Node JS(front and backend). Now I'm moving to latest Microsoft ASP.Net Core(.Net6) MVC. I love the way they are using c# code in Views(.cshtml). But I got into a situation that I could easily resolve by Javascript but not with c#. Below is the screen. I'm able to enter name and click on "Submit" button. It will return me the result grid. But I'm using return View code.

```
public IActionResult Index(Person p)
{
        string sPersonKeyword = HttpContext.Request.Form["Person_keyword"];
        DBDataGet(sPersonKeyword);
        return View();
}
```

The code above send back whole page, leading to my old value on search input box disappear. I know that I could change my technology to do MVC with Ajax in the cshtml, which I used to do in my Node JS projects. Is there any way I could do similar "Partial web page rendering" in cshtml views using c# coding.
I tried to create and use Partial view, it still refresh the whole page.

```
return PartialView("_IndexPartial",recipes);
```

Below is how my screen looks like:
[Screen design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnfOa.png)

Comment: you would need ajax if you are updating partial part of web page. why you wanted to avoid Ajax? check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392212/how-to-use-jquery-or-ajax-to-update-razor-partial-view-in-c-asp-net-for-a-mvc-p also you can search a bit about signalR

Comment: Thanks @KamranShahid for your input. The reason why I try to avoid Ajax is related to team development. Most of the memebers are not having experience for JavaScript. I try to get minimum effort to get people get adapt to new Microsoft MVC.

Comment: This may be helpful to you: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/06/01/ajax-without-javascript.aspx, but I think trying to use Ajax is a batter way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@KamranShahid and @AbyssWatch818 Thanks guys for the answers, in the end I was able to do regular c# MVC for most of the logic. And only that partial grid upgrade with Ajax. I guess that is currently only way. Let's hope Microsoft develop c# style of Ajax soon. Because I struggle a lot during debugging that Ajax part. But c# allow you to debug directly on cshtml file, which was amazing.

Comment: Consider leaving this as a comment